# Accessing a function variable from a called function's callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my code below, it's all working with the exception of return_info not getting setup. Is it possible to access the parent return_info variable from within the callback that is called by the request function?

```
module.exports = {
  fetch_template_by_id : function(id) {
    var request = require('request');
    var return_info = {}; //TO BE MODIFIED
    request('http://localhost:5000/templates/v1/template/' + id, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log("Success - Error = " + error + " | Response = " + response + " | Body = " + body);
        return_info.body = body;                  // Should Modify the top
        return_info.json = JSON.parse(body);      // Should Modify the top
        return_info.success = true;              // Should Modify the top
      } else {
        console.error("There was an error requesting template ID=" + id)
        return_info.error = error;                // Should Modify the top
        return_info.response = response;          // Should Modify the top
        return_info.success = false;              // Should Modify the top
      }
    });
    return return_info;
  }
}
```

EDIT: For Further reference this is the code that calls it.

```
app.get('/form', function (req, res) {
var template_helper = require('../services/template-helper');
var template = template_helper.fetch_template_by_id("BirthRecord");
console.log(template);
if (template.success === true) {
  res.render('form', {"template": template.json });
} else {
  res.render('index');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As request is asynchronous, it will execute after you have returned `return_info`. So, you need to provide a callback to the function as show below

```
module.exports = {
  fetch_template_by_id : function(id, cb) {
    var request = require('request');
    var return_info = {}; //TO BE MODIFIED
    request('http://localhost:5000/templates/v1/template/' + id, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log("Success - Error = " + error + " | Response = " + response + " | Body = " + body);
        return_info.body = body;                  // Should Modify the top
        return_info.json = JSON.parse(body);      // Should Modify the top
        return_info.success = true;              // Should Modify the top
      } else {
        console.error("There was an error requesting template ID=" + id)
        return_info.error = error;                // Should Modify the top
        return_info.response = response;          // Should Modify the top
        return_info.success = false;              // Should Modify the top
      }
      cb(return_info);
    });
  }
}

fetch_template_by_id('awesome', function (info) {
  console.log(info);
});
```

**EDIT - With the context**

You need to think along the callback ways if you want to start working with node.js, Below is the example on how you should do it.

```
app.get('/form', function (req, res) {
  var template_helper = require('../services/template-helper');
  template_helper.fetch_template_by_id("BirthRecord", function (template) {
    console.log(template);
    if (template.success === true) {
      res.render('form', {"template": template.json });
    } else {
      res.render('index');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This would work, but I need to not break the flow of the product as much as possible, I am new to node.js though, so I dunno what I can do. I posted the code that calls this, just so you can get more context. Your solution might still be helpful, I just don't know enough about node to post on that.

Comment: I edited, please check. You need to read about how to code using callbacks before using nodejs asynchronously.

Comment: So I just commited some code that looks almost identical to what you have above, and it worked perfectly. Your help before got me into the right mind set, thanks for confirming my thought process. Thanks.